# My annotation created with reflection API return null even when there is data

Tags: java, reflection, orm, annotations

so I'm building ORM Manager from scratch with reflection API, everything works fine but there is one annotation `@Table` that i created and it doesn't want to work as it should. So annotation looks like this

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Target(ElementType.TYPE)
   public @interface Table {
    String value() default "";
}
```

and I'm using it on my model class as so

```
@Entity
@Table(value = "Books")
public class Book {
```

and now i'm trying to get that value passed as a parameter like this

```
@Override
    void register(Class... entityClasses) throws SQLException {
        for (Class entityClass : entityClasses) {

            if (entityClass.isAnnotationPresent(Entity.class)) {

                String tableName;

                if (entityClass.isAnnotationPresent(Table.class)) {
                    tableName = entityClass.getClass().getDeclaredAnnotation(Table.class).value();
                } else {
                    tableName = entityClass.getSimpleName();
                }
```

Dont mind `@Entity` annotation it works fine. Only problem is that `@Table` annotation always returns null so it throws `NullPointerException` and crashing.

Where is a problem, how can i solve this. I already implemented `@Column` annotation and when i use `.value()` on `@Column` annotation it works fine so no clue why it doesn't work for `@Table`

@EDIT

So i just discovered that's not `Value` returning null but `.getAnnotation` but still no clue why is it returning null

```
Cannot invoke "teamblue.annotations.Table.value()" 
because the return value of "java.lang.Class.getAnnotation(java.lang.Class)" is null
```

Comment: I think you just want `entityClass.getDeclaredAnnotation(Table.class)` -- the class of `entityClass` is `Class`.

Comment: After using `entityClass.getDeclaredAnnotation(Table.class)` i can't get to `value()` method all i can do after is `entityClass.getDeclaredAnnotation(Table.class).annotationType()`

Answer (score -1):

The problem was a foreach loop, i had to pass generic types in it like that

```
 for (Class<?> entityClass : entityClasses)
```

Not sure how exactly but it did work so happy about it

Comment: There is nothing that extends `Class`. So, the only legal value there is `Class.class`. Which is rather pointless.

Comment: Using a raw type (`Class`) causes the entire line of code to be stripped of generics information at compile time, so the compiler does not know getDeclaredAnnotation is returning a Table instance.  If you turn on all compiler warnings, the compiler will tell you about such mistakes.

Comment: The problem was the missing `<?>` at the declaration of `entityClass` **and** the fact that you were calling `getClass()` on the `Class` as discussed [in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74131584/my-annotation-created-with-reflection-api-return-null-even-when-there-is-data/74132369#comment130885500_74131584) So your answer addresses the new problem you described in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74131584/my-annotation-created-with-reflection-api-return-null-even-when-there-is-data#comment130885830_74131584) but not the original question.